# how to get more efficient row counts and uniqueN in a very BIG dataset

Tags: r, data.table

I have got a very big dataset. It includes, say, three dimensions, i.e. firm ID, bank code, bank branches and distances of each firm to every bank branches.

I need to get these two stats in condition of some kilometers surrouding a firm:
(i) the number of banks, by identifying the uniqueN of bank code
(ii) the number of branches, by taking the sum of the number of bank branches

And I coded it like the following, but it's tedious and extremely slow and miles from the reputation of `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
n <- 1e7 # a simplified sample
DTsample <- data.table(Dist = abs(rnorm(n)*15 + 30), 
                       BankCode = sample(1:200, n, replace = TRUE),
                       firmID = sample(1:5000, n, replace = TRUE)
                       )[, BankBranch := .GRP, by = BankCode]

# (i) calculate uniqueN of bank code
DTsample[, .(Dleq05 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <=  5]), # banks to a firm is no further than 5 km
             Dleq15 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 15]), # banks to a firm is no further than 15 km
             Dleq25 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 25]),
             Dleq35 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 35]),
             Dleq45 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 45])), by = firmID]

# (ii) calculate the sum of the number of bank branches
DTsample[, .(Nleq05 = sum(+(Dist <=  5)), # branches (in rows) to a firm is no further than 5 km
             Nleq15 = sum(+(Dist <= 15)), # branches (in rows) to a firm is no further than 15 km
             Nleq25 = sum(+(Dist <= 25)),
             Nleq35 = sum(+(Dist <= 35)),
             Nleq45 = sum(+(Dist <= 45))), by = firmID]
```

Is it possible to run faster? I ran something like that in my real data, and it takes days.

Comment: try `setDTthreads(1)` before your query.

Comment: @jangorecki, thank you for your reply. It helps, but seems not substantial...

Comment: just to clarify, can the distance from the same bank code and same bank branch be different from 1 firm? e.g. `DTsample[firmID==1L & BankCode==1L & BankBranch==127]`. it is impt because when we check our results against your desired output, it will give different answers. and our solution is based on finding number of unique bank codes within some distance of each firm.

Comment: @chinsoon12, thank you for your answer. Sorry for the mistake in my shoddy code for random sample construction. What you said is right, only one unique BankBranch that is surrounding a certain firm in the real data.

Answer (score 0):

I think only the first 1 is slow. The dataset also has multiple distances for the same firmID, same bank code and same branch code which I have taken the liberty to fix.

Here is an option to first remove rows that are out of the maximum radius. Then, create centric circles of 5miles, 15, 25, 35 and 45 and count the number of unique bank codes within each circle. Then, fill up the empty outer rings because if a bank code exists in the inner ring, it is also in the empty outer ring.

data prep:

```
#remove bank codes that are too far
maxd <- 45
DT <- DTsample[Dist<=maxd]

#!!!!
#seems like sample dataset has diff dist for the same firmID, same bankcode and bankbranch
#hence use this to fix the issue
DT <- unique(DT, by=c("firmID", "BankCode", "BankBranch"))
```

actual code:

```
system.time({
  #round the distances into desired circles
  intv <- seq(5, maxd, 10)  
  DT[, Dist := intv[findInterval(Dist, c(0, intv))]]

  #count unique bank code per firmID per cirle
  setkeyv(DT, c("firmID","Dist","BankCode"))
  DT[, uq := {
      ri <- rleid(firmID, Dist, BankCode)
      ix <- which(!duplicated(firmID))[-1L]
      x <- replace(c(0, rep(NA, .N-1L)), ix, ri[ix-1L])
      ri - nafill(x, "locf")
  }]
  muq <- DT[, .(nuq=max(uq)), keyby=.(firmID, Dist)]

  #fill in missing bankcodes because if they exists in smaller rings, they must also be in the larger rings
  dat <- muq[CJ(firmID=unique(firmID), Dist=intv), on=.NATURAL][,
      nuq := nafill(nafill(nuq, "locf"), fill=0L), by=.(firmID)]

  #get desired output in wide format
  a1 <- dcast(dat, firmID ~ Dist, value.var="nuq")
  setnames(a1, names(a1)[-1L], sprintf("Dleq%02d", intv))
})
#   user  system elapsed
#   0.36    0.11    0.35
```

compare and check with OP's original code:

```
system.time({
  # (i) calculate uniqueN of bank code
  a1_0 <- DT[, .(Dleq05 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <=  5]), # banks to a firm is no further than 5 km
    Dleq15 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 15]), # banks to a firm is no further than 15 km
    Dleq25 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 25]),
    Dleq35 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 35]),
    Dleq45 = uniqueN(BankCode[Dist <= 45])), keyby = firmID]
})
#   user  system elapsed
#   1.52    1.81    2.69

fsetequal(a1, a1_0)
#[1] TRUE
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
n <- 1e7 # a simplified sample
DTsample <- data.table(Dist = abs(rnorm(n)*15 + 30), 
                       BankCode = sample(1:200, n, replace = TRUE),
                       firmID = sample(1:5000, n, replace = TRUE)
                       )[, BankBranch := .GRP, by = BankCode]
```

Maybe for the 2nd question, something less repetitive like:

```
a2 <- dcast(DT[, .N, .(firmID, Dist)][, N := cumsum(N), firmID],
    firmID ~ Dist, value.var="N")
setnames(a2, names(a2)[-1L], sprintf("Nleq%02d", intv))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is inspiring and improves a lot of efficiency.